# Arrange path order of line plot in >4.x Plotly

Tags: r, plot, plotly, linechart, r-plotly

I need to plot a path that does not strictly go from left to right but cross' itself on the y-axis, however since I upgraded to plotly 4.7 I cannot not do this. It was no problem in fx. 3.6

Does anyone know, how to tell plotly how to order the path?

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly) # > 4.x

data.frame(x = c(1:5,5:1),y = c(1:10)) %>%
  arrange(y) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~x,y = ~y) %>% add_lines()
```

[image]

if you look at the data.frame it should follow the red path:

```
data.frame(x = c(1:5,5:1),y = c(1:10)) %>% arrange(y)
   x  y
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4
5  5  5
6  5  6
7  4  7
8  3  8
9  2  9
10 1 10
```

Comment: `df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5,5:1),y = c(1:10)); with(df, plot(x,y)); with(df, lines(x,y))`

Comment: Also, look into `add_trace`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the mode in `plotly`:

```
 data.frame(x = c(1:5,5:1),y = c(1:10)) %>%
    arrange(y) %>%
    plot_ly(x = ~x,y = ~y, mode = 'lines+markers')
```

Graph would be:

[image]

Or you can use the following base-R solution:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5,5:1),y = c(1:10))
      with(df, plot(x,y))
      with(df, lines(x,y))
```

This will give you following plot:[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton @Masoud, I thought that 
    `data.frame(x = c(1:5,5:1),y = c(1:10)) %>%
      arrange(y) %>%
      plot_ly(x = ~x,y = ~y, mode = 'lines')` 
 and 
    `data.frame(x = c(1:5,5:1),y = c(1:10)) %>%
      arrange(y) %>%
      plot_ly(x = ~x,y = ~y) %>% add_lines()`
would do the same thing. Apparently not.